# Issue with multiple image write

Tags: php, fwrite

Now I am fed up with this issue, have been trying to fix it since 2-3 days.

**The problem:**

I am downloading certain images, and then writing them on to disk with php script.

The images are high resolution may be around 7000 pixels. The data is being downloaded properly.

When I write this data on to file, some time 1 image gets write, some times 2,3 etc.

The script is not showing any error and just breaks.
I don't have access to server logs and can't check those either.

It breaks after **curl_get_contents** , means where I write file, if I comment that section it works properly.

Below is the code:

```
<?php

    ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

    include_once("../config.php");
    include_once("../utils.php");

    $DIR = "../wallpapers";
    $URL = "Website url";

    $info = array();
  $dom = new domDocument;
  @$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($URL));
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($links as $tag){
    $iurl = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $lastHyphenAt = strrpos($iurl, "-");
        $iurl = substr ($iurl, 0, $lastHyphenAt).".jpg";
    $info[$i]["url"] = $iurl;
    $info[$i]["name"] = basename($iurl);    
    $i++;
  }


    foreach($info as $item){
        $url = $item["url"];
        $name = $item["name"];

        if(!file_exists($DIR."/".$name)){
            echo "Downloading: ".$url."<br><br>";
            $data = curl_get_contents($url);            
            $file = fopen($DIR."/".$name,"w") or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); 
            fwrite($file,$data);
            fclose($file);
        }else
            echo "Exists ".($DIR."/".$name)."<br><br>";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: i would add a line with var_dump($name) before fopen, just to check if the value of the variable is ok

Comment: The name is ok, since it already downloads few images, when I execute api again it downloads few others. But not in one go.

Answer (score 0):

you can write high resolution images by applying chunk functionality, check below code for the same :-

```
$chunk = 102400;
$filePointer = fopen($url, "rb");
if ($filePointer!=false){
        while (!feof($filePointer))
        {
            if($chunk<TOTALFILESIZE)
            {
                $fileData = fread($filePointer, 102400); //102400 is chunk size
                $myFile = $DIR."/".$_REQUEST['filename'].'.'.$_REQUEST['ext']; //store the file into temp. location
                chmod($myFile, 0777);
                $fp = fopen($myFile, 'a+');
                fwrite($fp, $fileData);
                fclose($fp);
            }       
        }
}
```

Comment: I have the data in $data variable, can you adjust the above code, looks like you are reading from file.

Comment: In the url you have to pass full image URL here and in totalfilesize you have to set your image file size there then this code will autoread your file and save it.

Comment: Please sent me your code so I can check it what is the issue.

Comment: You can download the above code and change url: www.pexels.com